# Audio keeps stuttering during audio/playback

Tags: sound, lubuntu

I'm using a HP Probook 6550b with Lubuntu on it. I've used various *buntus on this notebook with no sound issues. I don't know where the problem comes from. I'm playing a mp3, a video from the harddisk or youtube and from time to time I get this annoying stuttering that totally ruins it.